# Как получить в Activity данние из TextView, который находится в RecyclerView?

Tags: android

В `Activity` есть `RecyclerView`, внутри которого помещаются `СardView`. В каждой `СardView` есть две кнопки и `TextView`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на плюс значение `TextView` увеличивается на один, на минус - уменьшается на один. Мне нужно вывести этот `TextView` в `Activity` в поле, находящемся под `RecyclerView`.
Как взять данные этого `TextView` в `Activity`? (нажатие кнопок + и - обрабатывается в `Adapter`)

Comment: из активити вызываете mAdapter.getCounter() - что-то в таком духе. адаптер это прослойка между активити и ресайлером. все действия там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует создать interface:

```
public interface OnItemClick {
    void onClick (String value);
}
```

и Activity реализует этот interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClick {
    recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(MainActivity.this,onlineData, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

    @Override
    void onClick (String value){
        textView.setText(value); //значение которое пришло при клике в адаптере
    }
}
```

В Adapter:

```
  private OnItemClick mCallback;

RecycleAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> onlineData, OnItemClick mCallback){
    this.onlineData = onlineData;
    this.context = context;
    this.mCallback = mCallback;
 }
    ....

    public void increment(){
        int currentNos = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()) ;
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(++currentNos));
        mCallback.onClick(quantity.getText().toString());
    }

    public void decrement(){
        int currentNos = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()) ;
        quantity.setText(String.valueOf(--currentNos));
        mCallback.onClick(quantity.getText().toString());
    }
```

Ответ взят с [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009073/5797206)

Comment: Так все-таки `mCallback` или `listener`?

Comment: Спасибо, Подправил...